# What is the Philosophy Behind Relational Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEaecUuEqfc) on [Relational Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics) yesterday and my brain has been trying to comprehend it since.

The interpretation I currently have is this:
If an observer O measures the state S of a system, in doing so they themselves become entangled with that system.

To another observer O', the state of both S and O are still completely probabilistic until he measures them himself. However the state of S to O is now deterministic as they have become perfectly correlated with one another (through the measurement/entaglement). This is why to observer O it seems the wavefunction of S has collapsed as there is no longer any randomness in S relative to O (but this is not to say there is no randomness in the system (S+O) to an outside observer).

Further if I were not measuring a system (my friend let's say) they could be in one of a very large number of states with each having a certain probability. If I were to now look at them and 'measure' them, in effect one of these states is being sampled and I have become entangled/perfectly correlated with it.

My question is, have I completely missed the point or is this the general idea behind "Relational Quantum Mechanics"?

Comment: Assuming that *I* understand it (I have an opinion that makes sense, but I don't guarantee it's the same as what they're trying to communicate), yes, that is the general idea. Wave function collapse is not a property of isolated quantum systems, or a real effect of observation- it's a perceptual effect on the observer. Once you interact with something to observe it, you are now entangled with it. You yourself are also in a superposition, but any state of you can no longer observe all the other superposed states of the system that you're part of. Other observers outside the system still can.

Comment: I would argue that relational quantum mechanics replaces one difficulty (what's a measurement?) with another one (how can we separate the quantum system from the observer in a universe that has only one wave function?). As such it is a refinement of the original axiomatic definition of QM, which states that there are quantum systems (for which it can give examples from inside the theory), and then there are classical observers (which are external, since the theory can't model them itself). If I understand it correctly, the hope of RQM would be to define the observer internally.

Comment: @CuriousOne I thought the observer was being defined as a quantum system also (albeit a very complex one). Then what we think of as classical observers are in fact manifestations of very complex quantum systems. This is why the observer themselves become entangled with whatever they are measuring and is why the wave function of what they are measuring appears to collapse.

Comment: @rwolst: in conventional quantum mechanics the observer is a classical apparatus and it is an axiom of the theory, that all observables have an equivalent classical observer apparatus. There is no explanation given on how to construct an observer by means of wave functions alone. It is my understanding, that RQM tries to mend that, by showing that in a sufficiently large quantum system, the separation between a small part of the system and the rest creates these observers. IMHO, that can only happen by making additional thermodynamic assumptions, but the density matrix does that, already.

Comment: @CuriousOne one wavefunction for the entire Universe means that the Universe has entropy 0 which is impossible.

Comment: @Buuble: The entropy of an isolated system never decreases. Is the universe an isolated system? You decide! Do you see its entropy decreasing? I do not and I am not aware that anybody has. Other than that, the microcanonical ensemble description of Entropy counts possible states, not wavefunctions.

Comment: @CuriousOne I was thinking in terms of von Neumann entropy and the fact that pure states have entropy 0.

Comment: I keep trying to tell people this: quantum mechanics is a theory of information. I have never heard of "relational quantum mechanics" before I saw this post but from just the brief description you give in the question it looks like exactly what I have been evangelizing to my co-workers for a few years. It's the only way the theory can be both scientific and self-consistent (AFAICT).

Answer (score 2):

You used the letter $S$ ambiguously to refer to both a *system* and the *result of a measurement* made on that system.  **It's important to distinguish them**.

So the situation is that two observers $O_1$ and $O_2$ independently make a *measurement* $M$ of a *system* $S$ and agree that the *result of that measurement* is $X$.

It is tempting to conclude that the reason they agree is that $S$ is in fact in a state that corresponds to $X$, and that $X$ is a reflection of that underlying reality.

But that is not the case.  The math tells us that $O_1+O_2+S$ is a macroscopic system of mutually entangled particles.

If you trace over $S$ *(i.e. remove the degrees of freedom associated with $S$ from the description of the system)* what you are left with is a description of a macroscopic system of mutually entangled particles in classical correlation.  *That* is the reason $O_1$ and $O_2$ agree.

It has nothing to do with the state that $S$ is **"actually"** in.  *(I put "actually" in scare quotes because S is not actually in any particular state.)*

Comment: Hi user1136471, you should space you answer out so it's more easily readable.  Also consider using MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference