# How can we use usual notations in relational quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

in this [relational quantum mechanics paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9609002) Rovelli tries to reconstruct the theory avoiding to use the notion of a state associated to a particle. he says that the only correct thing would be to speak
of the information tbat an observer O has about a system S. he also says that it is an interpretation of quantum mechanics.
I wonder if we could use the usual notations in the spirit of QRM by always writing a subsript O to the state of the observed system ($ \phi_O$)
Please look at this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130849/what-is-the-philosophy-behind-relational-quantum-mechanics)
we have a two level system S observed by P and Q.
it is written ton consider the states of O + P + S.
we have to get things like uuu and ddd.
it is possible to rewrite this as $u_O. u_P.u$ but i have a problem with the third term. it seems to be "absolute".
i think that there are additional rules to use in the notations.